# I want to remove invalid characters from a wanabee XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want to remove invalid characters from an HTML file which is fetched from the web to be changed to an XML format.

I can't  change the source code, and doing it manually is not an option because I have to deal with hundreds of files per day.

I had been doing well until some of the HTML files showed up with a special character that is invalidating the code.

When I load the pretending XML file I get from the browser a warning

```
"This page contains the following errors:

error on line 137 at column 1: PCDATA invalid Char value 7
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."
```

After digging for the invalid character with a text editor I found: ⟩, a character apparently named: [&rang, &lang](http://tunes.org/wiki/html_20special_20characters_20and_20symbols.html), or maybe [&#9679](http://bundlr.com/b/special-characters), which is causing the problems.

I have tried to remove it with PHP but doesn't work.

```
//create arrays 
$find = array ('#&nbsp;#','#list#','#&rang;#'); 
$replace = array ('','',''); 

//replace with array values 
$list = preg_replace($find, $replace, $boletin_saveAsXml);
```

Any advise will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Perhaps you could use `strip_tags()`, `htmlspecialchar()`, or maybe it's an encoding issue. Is it all utf-8?

Comment: why would you need `preg_replace();` if you don't need a regular expression? Use `str_replace();` instead.

Comment: It comes in charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: My main concern is that I don't find how to address or identify this special character so I can "named" it in the php function that will try to remove it before moving to the xml task :)